# How to convert a Color32[] image from WebCamTexture to a UIImage in iOS?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know how to do this efficiently? I am using the EncodeToPNG() function, but the performance is really slow.

I am trying to capture the Ipad camera image using WebCamTexture and send it to the Objective C side to do some processing. I noticed that it is possible to send the native adress of the texture but how should I handle it on the ObjC side? Does anyone have any tips for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you say performance on EncodeToPNG is too slow, what you need to do is to hook into the code before the camera feed gets sent from iOS ( objc ) to Unity's WebCamTexture.

We used a similar technique with a plugin called CameraCaptureKit ( https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56673 ) to freeze the image send to Unity while waiting for the Flash and anti -shake being turned on.

In the xcode project generated by Unity you can open up CameraCapture.mm and find the function.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection
```

You can then modify the image sent to Unity's WebCamTexture by modifying this code. UnityDidCaptureVideoFrame is the code you want to plug into.

```
intptr_t tex = (intptr_t)CMVideoSampling_SampleBuffer(&self->_cmVideoSampling, sampleBuffer, &self->_width, &self->_height);
UnityDidCaptureVideoFrame(tex, self->_userData);
```

Cheers